# Multiple listviws and rows - Flutter

Tags: flutter

So Apperently I am doing this wrong (according to flutter)

```
 body:
          ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Text me'
                    )]
                    )
                )
              ),
            ),
          }),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: new RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () async { await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream'); },

              child: new Text("Change Station"),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('Craft beautiful UIs', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
              child: const FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

The error I am getting is:
`Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.`

Comment: I think you are new in flutter. You might wanna check this out: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to wrap everything in Column then wrap your ListView.builder with expanded.Like this

```
Column(
         children: [ Expanded(
           child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Text me'
                    )]
                    )
                )
            );
          })),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: new RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () async {  await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8015/stream'); 
                                   },

              child: new Text("Change Station"),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('Craft beautiful UIs', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
              child: const FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
                      ])
```

let me know if this work.